# Editing xml of views in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, xml, edit

I'm needing to move a on-prem SharePoint application that I wrote 5+ years ago to SharePoint Online.  When I did the development initially, I used SP Designer 2013 to edit the raw XML behind the views/forms.  Since SP Designer has been retired, what is the current method to view and edit the raw XML behind views/forms?

(I'm aware there is push to use the GUI editing tools provided by SP Online, but I want access to the raw XML for the details that the GUI editor doesn't do.)

Comment: Are you going to be using the modern or classic experience in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Modern, unless there is a reason to use classic

Comment: Since you’re using modern, have you explored the possibility of view & column formatting? See: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting  and  https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/view-samples  and  https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/column-samples

Comment: As I'm looking into it, I actually will probably use classic.  Ideally, I want the new site to be as close to the existing site (which was made in SP2013) as possible,  I'm writing this out of necessity (our on-prem servers are going away), not because we need any new features.  Are there tools for editing the XML in classic?